# linearly dependent vectors within a set of linearly independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

In general, if S is a set of linearly independent vectors, (apart from NOT having each vector equal to a linear combination of all the rest of the vectors ) that means that there cannot exist two vectors (or more) in S that are dependent. Is that right ?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the bit in parentheses is nonsense you are right. If $S$ is a linearly independent set, so is every subset of $S$. Worth noting too: it is the *set* that is linearly independent, not the vectors.

Comment: Any subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I meant the vectors within the set are linearly independent. "a set of"

Comment: @Seif-EddineAbdelkefi. OK so long as you realise that "linearly independent" is *not* a property of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\bv}{{\mathbf v}}
$$
Yes, the gist is right. Suppose that $\{\bv_1, \ldots, \bv_n\}$ is independent. but that $\{\bv_1, \ldots, \bv_k\}$ ($k < n$) is *dependent*. Then (by definition of dependent) there are numbers $c_1, \ldots, c_k$, not all zero, with
$$
c_1 \bv_1 + \ldots + c_k \bv_k = 0.
$$
If we define $c_{k+1} = \ldots = c_n = 0$, then we have a set of  numbers, not all zero, with
$$
c_1 \bv_1 + \ldots + c_k \bv_k + c_{k+1}\bv_{k+1} + \ldots + c_n \bv_n = \\
c_1 \bv_1 + \ldots + c_k \bv_k + 0\bv_{k+1} + \ldots + 0\bv_n = \\
c_1 \bv_1 + \ldots + c_k \bv_k = 
 0.
$$
which shows that the first set is actually *dependent* rather than independent.

You might complain that this proof works only if it's the *first* $k$ vectors that we assume dependent, but if not, we can reorder/re-label the set so that the assumed dependent vectors come first.

NB: The statement is still true even if your set of independent vectors is infinite, but the definitions of independent and dependent require some careful adjustments in that case, and the proof above no longer works directly (although the essential ideas do), because of things like "putting (potentially) infinitely many vectors first" doesn't quite make sense. Thanks to @ancientmathematician for prompting me to add this for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: I'd only add: there's no need to assume that we are dealing with a finite set.

Comment: Good point, although I suspect that OP is probably only thinking about finite sets; for infinite sets, there's the whole issue of cofinitely many coefficients being zero (or not, but then there are questions of convergence, etc.). I didn't want to cloud an essentially simple answer with those complexities. I'll add one sentence.

Comment: Not so: Defn: $S$ is LI if whenever $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i v_i=0$ where $a_i\in F$ and $v_i\in S$ we have all $a_i=0$.

Comment: That's a fine definition...but why should linear independence say that all *finite* sums that are zero have zero coefficients, rather than *all* sums? (*I* know the answer, but not every intro linear algebra student does!)  For most (intro) linear algebra texts, the def'n of linear independence is given for a set $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ of vectors, i.e. the set is implicitly assumed finite. If you generalize that definitely directly, you get something that's meaningless without some condition on the coefficients.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for your answer, it was really helpful !
A side question about your proof: is this a  a reduction to absurdity proof. (I am a new undergrad math student and I am still learning the different kind of proofs)

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction: we know $v_1...v_n$ is independent. We want to prove $v_1...v_k$ independent for $k < n$. We ASSUME the opposite -- that they are DEpendent, and show that $v_1...v_n$ is DEpendent, which is a contradiction to what we already know. Hence the assumption must be false.

Comment: @JohnHughes. The definition is the standard algebraic one. It's much cleaner and easier to work with - even for beginners. And it makes this question a triviality.

Comment: I understand that it's probably a very common definition. I also know that it's **not** very likely to be the one that OP has seen. I *could* have said 'your definition is lousy; here's a better one that handles situations you've never considered; I'll start by proving equivalence in the case you understand, and then the final proof will become trivial," but that didn't seem like good pedagogy to me. We may disagree on that, and that's OK of course.